# How will card.io handle Android M permissions to use application camera

Tags: android, android-permissions, card.io

Is there a roadmap for how card.io will be handling permission requests/checking to comply with the new Android M permission requirements? Will a permission check be added to the card.io SDK or is this something that will have to be verified before the CardIOActivity is started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [the card.io 5.1.0 release announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/card-io-sdk-announce/vUkGq--r0II):

> Add support for Android 23 new permission model for the Camera permission [#78](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/issues/78).  When permission is granted, the SDK performs as in previous versions.  When permission is or has already been denied, the SDK falls back to manual entry.  Note: this SDK does not call the `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` method and does not show a rationale.  It is up to the implementor whether or not to show the Camera permission rationale before opening the SDK.